# Call package only when run in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently using image_picker_web: ^2.1.1 package for my project and this project will run on both app and web, however when i include this package and run on app, it will trigger me quite a lot of error and i assume it's because inside the package for function that is only for web. My question is there a way to handle the package, so that it will import only when run on web, and exclude it when run in app

Comment: Try to disable compile web packages elements with constant `kIsWeb`

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot stop it from importing in mobile app but yes you can use check using `kIsWeb` and use the image_picker functionality only when it is true.